# My objects "exploaded" instead of playing the animation

Tags: units

So I'm new to Blender and doing my first project.

This is the one I'm following: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bpvh-9H8S1g

But the Tear It Down part for me looked different. Instead of playing the animation my objects "exploaded", and when I have rewinded this is what I got:

[image]

And now I cant go back, with Alt+Z

ps:

this is the animation that I got

[image]

Is there a fix for this?
Even if not, I just want to know what happened, or what may have cased this.

Thanks.

Comment: typically this happens if either the transforms are not apply (to fix: apply transform with ctrl-a) or if rigid bodies overlap. To make sure what the reason is, please provide your blend file.

Comment: hello, heres my blend file https://easyupload.io/1izmek

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it says in the comments under your video:

You have ALL of your cubes in one place. The must not intersect. So you "forgot" to move your cubes like he did in the video.

To move your cube, select it, then tap G then you can move it with your mouse.

Or better, press G X -> then it only moves in x direction.

same with G Y or G Z.

[image]

Comment: Ohh, 
I've read the video desc, but not the comments. Turns out I really should have.

Thanks Chris!

Comment: you are welcome ;)